# Android Studio:Assertion failed: Write access is allowed inside write-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runWriteAction())

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have installed Android studio and trying to run sample app with gradle
The whole thing is :

> Throwable: Assertion failed: Write access is allowed inside write-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runWriteAction())

How can I fix it? I could not find any solution.
Is any one familiar with this error, I'd appreciate any solutions?

Comment: try it with..changed permission of Directory

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Android Studio (not a directory permission problem). Does restarting fix it?

Comment: yep thank zapl  after restarting it is showing error like
Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: This is a bug. You should get a full stacktrace from the debug log (Help menu > Show logs) and file a bug at b.android.com.

Comment: This seems like a bug in android plugin of intellij IDE. This kind of error sent by intellij when its plugins(android plugin in this case)try to write files outside of Application.runWriteAction().